# What is the quickest way to duplicate/clone a table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I know that I could do `CREATE TABLE tbl_2 AS (select * from tbl_1)`

But is there a better/faster/stronger way to do this? I am talking about performance more than anything else. The tables are all denormalised and I do not have any foreign key constraints to worry about.

*EDIT*

May be there isn't any better way? Ref: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55661/how-to-duplicate-huge-postgres-table

Comment: `create table as ... select ...` is as fast as it gets. Btw: the parentheses around the select are totally useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way really depends on what exactly you're hoping to accomplish.

If you want to keep all the constraints and indexes from the original table you can use the `LIKE` clause in your `CREATE TABLE` statement like so:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_2 (LIKE tbl_1 INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS);
```

But that just creates an empty table.  You would still have to copy in the data.

Comment: I am hoping to have the fastest in terms of performance. Also not really bothered about the constraints here because my use case does not demand it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use something like the following:

```
$ pg_dump -t tbl_1 | sed -e 's/^SET search_path = .*$/SET search_path = tmpschema, pg_catalog;' > table.sql
$ psql -d test -c 'CREATE SCHEMA tmpschema'
$ psql -1 -d test -f table.sql
$ psql -d test -c 'ALTER TABLE tmpschema.tbl_1 RENAME TO tbl_2; ALTER TABLE tmpschema.tbl_2 SET SCHEMA public; DROP SCHEMA tmpschema'
```

Perhaps it is not faster than `CREATE TABLE ... AS (SELECT ...)`, but it will copy all indexes and constraints as well.

Comment: The LIKE clause in a create table statement can create a new table with the same indexes and constraints a bit more easily than using pg_dump.

Comment: Right, but it does not copy the table contents. You could run `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...` and then `INSERT INTO ... (SELECT ...)`, but that would certainly be slow, because the indexes and constraints are already defined. `pg_dump` dumps the indexes and constraints *after* the table data.